# Initial class styles remain after toggleClass

Tags: jquery, css

I have a read more button that toggles classes when clicked. Each class has an icon (plus and minus) set as background image. It changes class and styles just fine except that the icon of the initial class (.show) is always active on the homepage even though the inspector shows the correct background image URL. Any ideas on why this is happening on just the homepage and not on any of the other pages?

```js
    // Read more
        $(".read-more").click(function(){
          // Toggle read-more button class
          $(this).toggleClass("show hide");
    
          // Change button text depending on state
          if( $(this).hasClass("hide") ) {
            $(".read-more_button").html("Hide");
          } else if( $(this).hasClass("show") ) {
            $(".read-more_button").html("Read more");
          }
    
          // Toggle content class
          $(".content-sidebar").toggleClass("longtext");
        });
```

```css
    .read-more {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            height: 100px;
            right: 0;
            border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0 20px;
            cursor: pointer;
            background: none;
    
            &.show {
                background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 55%); /* FF3.6-15 */
                background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 55%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
                background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 55%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    
                button.read-more_button {
                    background: url('assets/plus-more.png') 0 / 14px no-repeat transparent;
                } 
            }
    
            &.hide {
                background: transparent;
    
                button.read-more_button {
                    background: url('assets/minus-less.png') 0 / 14px no-repeat transparent;
                }
            }
    
            button.read-more_button {
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 15px;
                left: 30px;
                right: 30px;
                border: none;
                background: none;
                padding: 0 0 0 20px;
                color: $gray-dark;
                cursor: pointer;
                outline: none;
            }
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <div class="read-more show">
```

*Edit for clarification*

Comment: create jsfiddle for issue explanation. Here it is half html code

Comment: It's working fine for me https://jsfiddle.net/rzbjcfju/ Either your local images are named slightly differently or it's an issue with LESS. Try using vanilla CSS and see if the problem persists.

Comment: @gaynorvader I'll see if vanilla CSS changes anything, good idea. I should note that this issue only exists on the homepage. Every other page works as it should.

Comment: Likely something is overwriting the CSS on your homepage, perhaps you have a button with more specificy that's preventing your hide class from being displayed.